# Check a Date is between two dates in Java

Tags: java, date

One thing I want to know is how to calculate what date will it be 10 days from today.

Second thing is to check if one Date is between two other Dates.
For example, let's say I have an app that shows what events I need to do in the next 10 days (planner). Now how can I see if the date I assigned to an event is between today and the date that is 10 days from today?

Answer (score 20):

Manipulating and comparing dates using `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` is pretty a pain, that's why [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) exist. None of the answers as far have covered the **time** in question. The comparisons may fail when the dates have a non-zero time. It's also unclear whether you want an *inclusive* or *exclusive* comparison. Most of the answers posted so far suggest *exclusive* comparision (i.e. May 24 is **not** between May 20 and May 24) while in real it would make more sense to make it *inclusive* (i.e. May 24 **is** between May 20 and May 24).

---

> *One thing I want to know is how to calculate what date will it be 10 days from today.*

With the standard Java SE 6 API, you need [`java.util.Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for this.

```
Calendar plus10days = Calendar.getInstance();
plus10days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 10);
```

With JodaTime you would do like this:

```
DateTime plus10days = new DateTime().plusDays(10);
```

---

> *Second thing is to check if one Date is between two other Dates. For example, let's say I have an app that shows what events I need to do in the next 10 days (planner). Now how can I see if the date I assigned to an event is between today and the date that is 10 days from today?*

Now comes the terrible part with `Calendar`. Let's prepare first:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar plus10days = Calendar.getInstance();
plus10days.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 10);
Calendar event = Calendar.getInstance();
event.set(year, month - 1, day); // Or setTime(date);
```

To compare reliably using `Calendar#before()` and `Calendar#after()`, we need to get rid of the time first. Imagine it's currently 24 May 2010 at 9.00 AM and that the event's date is set to 24 May 2010 without time. When you want inclusive comparison, you would like to make it `return true` at the same day. I.e. both the `(event.equals(now) || event.after(now))` or -shorter but equally- `(!event.before(now))` should return true. But actually none does that due to the presence of the time in `now`. You need to clear the time in all calendar instances first like follows:

```
calendar.clear(Calendar.HOUR);
calendar.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
calendar.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
calendar.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
calendar.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

Alternatively you can also compare on day/month/year only.

```
if (event.get(Calendar.YEAR) >= now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    && event.get(Calendar.MONTH) >= now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    && event.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) >= now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
{
    // event is equal or after today.
}
```

Very verbose all.

With JodaTime you can just use [`DateTime#toLocalDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate%28%29) to get the date part only:

```
LocalDate now = new DateTime().toLocalDate();
LocalDate plus10days = now.plusDays(10);
LocalDate event = new DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0).toLocalDate();
if (!event.isBefore(now) && !event.isAfter(plus10days)) {
    // Event is between now and 10 days (inclusive).
}
```

Yes, the above is really *all* you need to do.

Answer (score 16):

```
public static boolean between(Date date, Date dateStart, Date dateEnd) {
    if (date != null && dateStart != null && dateEnd != null) {
        if (date.after(dateStart) && date.before(dateEnd)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: Another suggested variant:

```
public Boolean checkDate(Date startDate, Date endDate, Date checkDate) { 
    Interval interval = new Interval(new DateTime(startDate), 
                                     new DateTime(endDate));   
    return interval.contains(new DateTime(checkDate)); 
}
```

Comment: this is using JodaTime, isn't it?

Comment: and it's a massive NULL-checking anti-pattern example :)

Answer (score 5):

Use JodaTime calendar replacement classes: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 Specially if you are doing plain date (not datetime) calculation, JodaTime's LocalDate class  gives you all you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **before**, **after** and **compareTo** methods of **Date** class.

Here're some examples

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CompareDate.shtml

http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-287.html

http://www.esus.com/javaindex/j2se/jdk1.2/javautil/dates/comparingdates.html

And here's **API** on **Date** class

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

To add ten days:

```
Date today = new Date();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(today);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 10);
```

To check if between two dates:

```
myDate.after(firstDate) && myDate.before(lastDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the initial answer and modified it a bit.  I consider if the dates are equal to be "inside"..

```
private static boolean between(Date date, Date dateStart, Date dateEnd) {
    if (date != null && dateStart != null && dateEnd != null) {
        return (dateEqualOrAfter(date, dateStart) && dateEqualOrBefore(date, dateEnd));

    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean dateEqualOrAfter(Date dateInQuestion, Date date2)
{
    if (dateInQuestion.equals(date2))
        return true;

    return (dateInQuestion.after(date2));

}
private static boolean dateEqualOrBefore(Date dateInQuestion, Date date2)
{
    if (dateInQuestion.equals(date2))
        return true;

    return (dateInQuestion.before(date2));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if date is between two dates, here is simple program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    String oeStartDateStr = "04/01/";
    String oeEndDateStr = "11/14/";

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Integer year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    oeStartDateStr = oeStartDateStr.concat(year.toString());
    oeEndDateStr = oeEndDateStr.concat(year.toString());

    Date startDate = sdf.parse(oeStartDateStr);
    Date endDate = sdf.parse(oeEndDateStr);
    Date d = new Date();
    String currDt = sdf.format(d);


    if((d.after(startDate) && (d.before(endDate))) || (currDt.equals(sdf.format(startDate)) ||currDt.equals(sdf.format(endDate)))){
        System.out.println("Date is between 1st april to 14th nov...");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Date is not between 1st april to 14th nov...");
    }
}
```